# Amazon API - MWS and AWS API

Tags: asp.net, web-services, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can any one Explain me the following Things,

- What is the difference between Amazon MWS API and AWS API, and What other APIS Amazon have?
- Currently if I want to get Complete Information of All products on my Seller Account ,and What to Add and Update Product Pragmatically via .net
- Do  I need to register one by one on both API?
- Which API Should I go For, also Please Provide the Related links to get Started?
- What are the Advantages and Limitations of Both APIs

PS: I want to use it in .Net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MWS API has to do with selling products in the **Amazon** Marketplace.

> Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS) is an integrated Web
>   service API that helps Amazon sellers to programmatically exchange
>   data on listings, orders, payments, reports, and more. XML data
>   integration with Amazon enables higher levels of selling automation,
>   which helps sellers grow their business. By using Amazon MWS, sellers
>   can increase selling efficiency, reduce labor requirements, and
>   improve response time to customers.

The AWS API is a general purpose API for cloud infrastructure, i.e. servers, queues, databases etc so can be used to build any type of application that may or may not have anything to do with the retail side of amazon.com.

It is entirely possible that you may need only one or both of these API's depending on what you are doing.

If you are not selling products on amazon's marketplace, then you would not need the MWS API, if you are selling products in the marketplace, you would likely use the MWS API, but you may also use the AWS API to build out your complete solution.

The distinction is that while you may use the MWS API to sell products on Amazon.com, you might choose to build the rest of your solution on rackspace or azure (for example), so you wouldn't need the AWS API in this case, just the MWS API.

If you can provide more information on what you are trying to do, we cqan give you a better answer.

Comment: I need to get Product Information from Webstore like Price, Description, also want to add products in the WebStore

Comment: Then you will only need to use the MWS API for that.

Comment: What About Adding Products, all docs i saw are related to View not to Add